# what is an getErrorCode()==1767 in sybase?

Tags: sql, exception, sybase

I tried searching the Exception thown for `getErrorCode()` in sybase,but couldnot get the required information.I tried searching the minor codes also.Can someone please tell what this exception means?This is a `SQLException` and the `errorcode=1767`.what does this indicate? And how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of variable length columns exceeds limit of %d for allpage locked tables. %s for '%.*s' failed.

Explanation:

Adaptive Server could not perform the requested action. Modify your command to meet the Adaptive Server requirement for the objects or variables shown in the error message.

http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/svrtsg/@Generic__BookTextView/76240;pt=77267

Comment: thank you so much but can you please explain when we get this error and how to overcome this? i mean iam using an alter table cmd what might have resulted in this error?

Comment: can you please show the the cmd line that you use so i can figure it out. and please don't forget to click the upvote and select my answer if i answered your question successfully :)